# Issue with comparing strings in a binary tree

Tags: java

This is part of an assignment checking similar words in a binary tree. I've been stuck on this bug for too long, and would greatly appreciate any help towards solving this.

- Input: String "achiev"
- Output: all strings accepted by
  [a-z]achiev OR a[a-z]chiev OR ... OR achiev[a-z]
- Problem: The algorithm produces the string "achieve", but .compareTo() and .equals() tells otherwise.

  ```
  public class Problem {

  static ArrayList<String> oneRedundantChar(String s) {

  char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
  char[] arr = new char[(s.length()*2) + 1];
  char[] sarr = s.toCharArray();

  for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i+= 2) {
      arr[i] = sarr[(i-1)/2];
  }
  char[] temp = arr.clone();

  ArrayList<String> reparr = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int i = 0; i < s.length()*2+1; i += 2) {
      for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
          arr[i] = alphabet[j];
          reparr.add(String.valueOf(arr));
      }
      arr = temp.clone();
  }

  return reparr;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (String s : oneRedundantChar("achiev")) {

      System.out.println(s);

      if (s.compareTo("achieve") == 0) {
          System.out.println("Success");
      }
      if(s.equals("achieve")) {
          System.out.println("Success");
      }
  ```

Comment: Your approach looks morbidly inefficient to me. Have you heard of Levenshtein distance?

Answer (score 0):

Your "s" String is spaced out (eg. " a c h i e v") and the redundant char is placed somewhere in the space. So even if "achieve" is generated, it is with spaces (" a c h i e ve") which is obviously not the same in terms of equals or compareTo as the word "achieve". When you put the generated string into the result array (`reparr.add(String.valueOf(arr));`), you need to pick only the non-empty characters.

Comment: No, here is an example. System.out.println("GG" + s + "GG"); outputs: GGachiesvGG
GGachietvGG
GGachieuvGG
GGachievvGG
GGachiewvGG
GGachiexvGG
GGachieyvGG
GGachiezvGG
GGachievaGG
GGachievbGG
GGachievcGG
GGachievdGG
GGachieveGG
GGachievfGG

Comment: Can you add printing of s.length() to it? When I run System.out.println(s + "-" + s.length()); it always prints the length of 13.

Comment: Interesting. I get the same results. How is this possible when all empty-spaces should be revealed by the "GG" + s + "GG" concatenation?

Comment: @mortenkd likely they aren't spaces, but some non-printable characters. Question for you: Is there a specific reason why you want to over-complicate it by using arrays instead of just using the `String` API?

Comment: @BackSlash: you are right, to be precise they are zero-byte chars, because that's what the cells of a "new char[]" empty array are initialized to. In my Intellij they print out as spaces, apparently in mortenkd's environment they are just swallowed.

Comment: No, I guess I could solve it in a more readable fashion by concatenating substrings. Still, it would be nice to what is failing in the current code.

Comment: @AdamMichalik I'm using intelliJ aswell. (14.1.4). Do you know how to identify zero-byte chars with java's regex?

Comment: @mortenkd The answer seem to be simple. In your code you double the length of the array (`char[] arr = new char[(s.length()*2) + 1];`) and then you loop incrementing the index `i` by `2` each time, which ends up in having `arr[i]` filled and `arr[i+1]` empty. Simply don't do that, create an array of `s.length() + 1` and use `i++` instead of `i+=2`.

Comment: Note that you are filling in every second array cell with the original word letter:

`for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i+= 2) {
    arr[i] = sarr[(i-1)/2];
}`

Comment: @AdamMichalik Thats intentional, and inserting new chars inbetween will satisfy the quasi-regex in the output text. (Given that all non-[a-z]-chars are removed).